# Should I implement IDisposable to free "unmanaged" memory?

Tags: c++-cli

Let's say I'm implementing some wrapper class `Foo` in C++/CLI. Naturally if I'll create a dtor (`Foo::~Foo`), it'll become an `IDisposable` implementation.

IDisposable is typically used to allow immediate release of some "scarce" resource: GDI resources, file handles etc. However, if my IDisposable simply frees memory (e.g. it simply performs `free` or `delete`), shouldn't it be done in a regular finalizer (`Foo::!Foo`), whenever that happens?

I mean, we're okay with the idea that .NET frees memory whenever it likes to, so why give granular control over something that's essentially just freeing memory?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think that releasing memory as early as possible (i.e. as soon as you don't need it) is a good principle.
Sure, the GC will kick in and free it, eventually. But the GC uses a single thread to call all finalizers, which can have a bad impact on performance, if there are a lot of finalizers to call.

And you may not feel much difference on a desktop app with a single client, but imagine a server app with hundreds or thousands of clients.

Comment: But you don't expect the same control over deallocation with managed.NET objects, so why with unmanaged objects?

For a .NET program, managed objects might be the majority of its allocations, and you don't free those "as soon as you don't need them".